# Exception thrown: read access violation. **head** was 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I am writing a Linked list in C. This is my code. I cannot really see any logic error here but when printing in while loop, after the last node is printed it does not jump out of the loop but keep looping then give me this error "Exception thrown: read access violation. **head** was 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred" on the "head" pointer in the loop.

```
// ass0.c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC // need this to get the line identification
//_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF); // in main, after local declarations
//NB must be in debug build
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE } BOOL;
struct Frame {
char* frameName;
struct Frame* pNext;
};
typedef struct {
char* animationName;
struct Frame* frames;
}Animation;
// Forward declarations
void InitAnimation(Animation*);
void InsertFrame(Animation*);
//void DeleteFrame(Animation*);
//void EditFrame(Animation*);
void ReportAnimation(Animation*);
//void CleanUp(Animation*);
int main(void)
{
char response;
BOOL RUNNING = TRUE;
Animation RG;
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
InitAnimation(&RG);
while (RUNNING)
{
    printf("MENU\n 1. Insert a Frame at the front\n 2. Delete last Frame\n 3. Edit a Frame\n 4. Report the Animation\n 5. Quit\n");
    scanf("%c", &response);
    switch (response)
    {
    case '1':InsertFrame(&RG); break;
    //case '2':DeleteFrame(&RG); break;
    //case '3':EditFrame(&RG); break;
    case '4':ReportAnimation(&RG); break;
    //case '5':RUNNING = FALSE; CleanUp(&RG); break;
    default:printf("Please enter a valid option\n");
    }
}
return 0;
  }

  void InitAnimation(Animation* newAnimation) {
newAnimation = malloc(sizeof(Animation));
newAnimation->animationName = "Animation_1";
newAnimation->frames = NULL;
 }

 void InsertFrame(Animation* animation) {
printf("Insert a Frame in the Animation\n");
char fName[50];
printf("Please enter the Frame Name: ");
scanf("%s", fName);

struct Frame *newFrame; 
newFrame = malloc(sizeof(struct Frame));
int nameSize = strlen(fName);
newFrame->frameName = malloc(nameSize + 1);
strcpy(newFrame->frameName, fName);
newFrame->pNext = 0;

//struct Frame* head;

if (animation->frames == NULL) 
    animation->frames = newFrame;
    //head = animation->frames;
    //head->pNext = NULL;
    //head = animation->frames;


else {
    //head = animation->frames;
    newFrame->pNext = animation->frames;
    animation->frames = newFrame;

    /*while (head != NULL) {
        newFrame->pNext = *head;
        animation->frames = newFrame;
        printf("%s", *head->frameName);
        head = head->pNext;
    }*/

    //head = animation->frames;
    printf("\n");
}
}

void ReportAnimation(Animation* animation) {
printf("Animation name is Animation_1\n");
printf("Report the Animation\n");
struct Frame* head = animation->frames;
//printf("%s\n", head->frameName);

while (head) {
    printf("%s\n", head->frameName);
    head = head->pNext;
}
//printf("%d", count);
  }
```

Comment: Please fix code formatting by editing your post. This code isn't readable.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!   amongst (many) other problems, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  for such things as the prototype for `malloc()`.

Comment: strongly suggest replacing this statement: `typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE } BOOL;` with: `#include <stdbool.h>` (which exposes `false` `true` `bool`, etc)  Note: the exposed items are all lower case

Comment: strongly suggest removing all the `CrtSetDbgFlag()` and related calls

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `scanf("%s", fName);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (in this case, any value other than 1 indicates an error)  2) when using the input format conversion specifier '%s' and/or '%[...]', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those items always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior  I.E. `if( scanf("%s", fName) != 1 ) { // handle error }`

Comment: OT: regarding: `newFrame = malloc(sizeof(struct Frame));`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" )` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char fName[50];` This contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.   Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give 'magic' numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: The posted code contains several memory leaks from allocating memory via `malloc()` but never calling `free()` for each of those allocated memory areas.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix any messages from the compiler.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnuu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the function `InitAnimation` does not make sense

```
void InitAnimation(Animation* newAnimation) {
newAnimation = malloc(sizeof(Animation));
newAnimation->animationName = "Animation_1";
newAnimation->frames = NULL;
 }
```

and hence the program in whole is incorrect.

The original object

```
Animation RG;
//...
InitAnimation(&RG);
```

is not initialized. The parameter of the function is just overwritten.

The object of the type `Animation` is already created in main due to the definition

```
Animation RG;
```

You need only to initialize its data members.

Remove the statement with the malloc call

```
void InitAnimation(Animation* newAnimation) {
newAnimation->animationName = "Animation_1";
newAnimation->frames = NULL;
 }
```

And in general you should allocate dynamically memory for the string that will be pointed to by the data member `animationName`.

The function cam look the following way

```
int InitAnimation( Animation *newAnimation, const char *name ) 
{
    newAnimation->animationName = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );

    int success = newAnimation->animationName !+ NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        strcpy( newAnimation->animationName, name );
        newAnimation->frames = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and called like

```
Animation RG;
//...
InitAnimation(&RG, "Animation_1" );
```

Pay attention to that you need to include the header `<stdlib.h>` where the functions `malloc` and `free` are declared.

Comment: That fixed my problem, thanks. But could you please explain a bit more why I should not use malloc here for the parameter? Shouldn't I allocate the space for the whole "Animation" struct first?

Comment: @SunZhuan The object of the type Animation is already created in main due to the definition Animation RG;. You need only to initialize its data members.